# Newbie Java: creating and writing a txt file with numbers in word format?

Tags: java, methods, printwriter

Getting ready for my first exam in Java and having a certain problem with a method. The following problem is just one method of four that will be combined into a single Java file.

> **Problem:**
>
> Write the code to create a new file called “exam1.txt” and print the
> following text to the file:
>
> Line One
> Line Two
> Line Three

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class problem2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String exam1 = "Exam1.txt";
        
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(exam1);
        for(int n = 0; n < 4; n++){
            printWriter.printf("Line %d\n", n);
        }
        printWriter.close();

    }

}
```

What I'm stuck on is figuring out how to convert the numbers into the actual words; for example, "1" into "One". Was my choice of the for loop even correct for this problem? I know how to do it the long way by printing out each line but figured I'd learn the correct way.

Comment: You need to use arrays and write code to do the conversion. There is no "automatic" way to do this other than to write your program. Go for it. You're here a bit prematurely since you don't have a real attempt yet in place. I suggest that you give it a go on your own first, and then come back with a real attempt if still stuck.

Comment: Presumably the `"One"`, `"Two"` and `"Three"` should be hardcoded somewhere. It's questionable whether you even need to use a loop at all, as opposed to just printing those three literal strings to the file. I'm 99% sure that converting decimal numbers to their English representations is not what the assignment is asking you to do.

Comment: You guys were right, I was going at it the wrong way. I added an array and it worked, 'String number[]= {"One", "Two", "Three"};'

Comment: You're better off using a Map if you're going to go that way, so you can explicitly tie the int to the String:  `Map<Integer, String> textForNumbers = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); textForNumbers.put(new Integer(1), "One"; textForNumbers.put(new Integer(2), "Two"; textForNumbers.put(new Integer(3), "Three";`  Then you can call `testForNumbers.get(n)` to get "One" if n==1.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm stuck on is figuring out how to convert the numbers into the
>   actual words.

Here is code to convert number to word. This will help you

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NumberToString
{

    public enum hundreds {OneHundred, TwoHundred, ThreeHundred, FourHundred, FiveHundred, SixHundred, SevenHundred, EightHundred, NineHundred}
    public enum tens {Twenty, Thirty, Forty, Fifty, Sixty, Seventy, Eighty, Ninety}
    public enum ones {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine}
    public enum denom {Thousand, Lakhs, Crores}
    public enum splNums { Ten, Eleven, Twelve, Thirteen, Fourteen, Fifteen, Sixteen, Seventeen, Eighteen, Nineteen}
    public static String text = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Number to convert into words");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long num = sc.nextInt();
        int rem = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(num > 0)
        {
            if(i == 0){
                rem = (int) (num % 1000);
                printText(rem);
                num = num / 1000;
                i++;
            }
            else if(num > 0)
            {
                rem = (int) (num % 100);
                if(rem > 0)
                    text = denom.values()[i - 1]+ " " + text;
                printText(rem);
                num = num / 100;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if(i > 0)
            System.out.println(text);
        else
            System.out.println("Zero");
    }

    public static void printText(int num)
    {
        if(!(num > 9 && num < 19))
        {
            if(num % 10 > 0)
                getOnes(num % 10);

            num = num / 10;
            if(num % 10 > 0)
                getTens(num % 10);

            num = num / 10;
            if(num > 0)
                getHundreds(num);
        }
        else
        {
            getSplNums(num % 10);
        }
    }

    public static void getSplNums(int num)
    {
        text = splNums.values()[num]+ " " + text;
    }

    public static void getHundreds(int num)
    {
        text = hundreds.values()[num - 1]+ " " + text;
    }

    public static void getTens(int num)
    {
        text = tens.values()[num - 2]+ " " + text;
    }

    public static void getOnes(int num)
    {
        text = ones.values()[num - 1]+ " " + text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no "right" way to do this, but I would recommend that you separate the concerns here, as that's generally good practice as you get into higher-order methods.  You're trying to do two things here: convert an int into a String, and then format the resulting String(s) into a series of lines written into a file.  Put each of those pieces of functionality into separate methods: one that converts ints to their String representation (however you end up implementing that), and one that does all the file-writing stuff and calls the int-conversion method in the process.

And I disagree with @arshajii's statement that maybe you should just write three println() statements, which would duplicate functionality (the formatting of the printf() statement would be duplicated) while co-mingling the concerns.  I might well do that in some code I write in the real world (depending on the situation), but that's not how I'd approach an exam in an intro to programming course, and it's not the general mindset I'd suggest for a student just learning good development practices.

As far as the actual problem that I know you're asking (how do I turn the ints into their corresponding String value), since you have a short, well-defined set of values, you could use a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)...